# Unintended behaviour when modifying string

Tags: java, string, replace, substring

Say I have an input like this
    `A5]-A4]-A3]-A2]-A1]-A0]`
or like this
    `I=A4]-A5]pABSI)<=((A0]-A1])^2+(A2]-A3])^2)^0.5<=I}`
I'm trying to replace all occcurances of `A<number>]` to `A[<number>]`, where  is anything between 0 and `Integer.MAX`, therefore the desired output would look like this
`A[5]-A[4]-A[3]-A[2]-A[1]-A[0]` and
`I=A[4]-A[5]pABSI)<=((A[0]-A[1])^2+(A[2]-A[3])^2)^0.5<=I}`

But for some reason the output looks like this:
`A[5]-A[[4]-A[3]-A[2]-A[1]-A0]` and
`I=A[4]-A[5]pABSI)<=((A[0]-A[1])^2+(A[[2]-A3])^2)^0.5<=I}`

Code so far:

```
private String finalPrg = "";
private int MAIN_LOOP = 0;

private void eval(String s) {

    while (MAIN_LOOP < s.length()) {
// more cases here, irrelevant
        switch (s.charAt(MAIN_LOOP)) {
            evalArrayGetter(finalPrg, MAIN_LOOP);
            break;
        default:
            finalPrg += s.charAt(MAIN_LOOP);
            break;
        }
        MAIN_LOOP++;
    }
}

private void evalArrayGetter(String s, int p) {
    int i;
    for (i = p-1; i > 0; i--) {
        if (s.charAt(i)=='A') {
            break;
        }
    }
    finalPrg =s.substring(0,i+1) + "[" +s.substring(i+1)+"]";
}
```

For some reason, one pair of brackets is not placed correctly, and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Is this homework where you are not allowed to use stuff in the "standard library"? If not, regex will be very helpful.

Comment: Is this a some sort of compiler you're writing? If yes, then doing it using simple text transformation into Java code could bite you real hard later on. You should do some research on Lexer (it splits program in small managable chunks), and a Parser(assesses chunks from Lexer and builds a tree using your defined rules (commonly EBNF)). Libraries available for these, as well as it isn't too hard to implement yourself. Personally I've written a Lexer using a finite automaton approach, and a Parser using the LL(1) algorithm.

Comment: @Sweeper I don't really know how regex works and researching about it wasn't really helping me a lot. And no, it's not a homework.

Comment: @Coderino Javarino I'll do that, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution with regex:

```
String result = yourString.replaceAll("A(\\d+])", "A[$1");
```

Explanation:

`A(\d+])` matches `A` followed by a series of digits, then by a `]`. It captures the series of digits and the `]` into group 1. `replaceAll` replaces everything in that string that matches the pattern with the second parameter, `A[$1`. Here, `$1` means group 1. So it replaces with `A[` followed by what is captured in group 1.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I knew Regex would do it, but I don't have any experience with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
String result = s.replaceAll("A(\\d+)\\]", "A[$1]");
```